# How to create a touchpoint DataFrame from a list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, data-manipulation

I working on a Python project that has a DataFrame like this:

```
row1 = ['BBB', 'AAA', 'CCC']
row2 = ['CCC']
row3 = ['DDD', 'AAA']
row4 = ['DDD', 'BBB', 'AAA', 'EEE', 'CCC']
row5 = ['EEE', 'AAA', 'EEE', 'CCC']
data = {'List': [row1, row2, row3, row4, row5],
        'Path_length':  [3, 1, 2, 5, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

which leads to:

```
|     |             List                   |   Path_length   | 
|  0  | ['BBB', 'AAA', 'CCC']              |       3         |  
|  1  | ['CCC']                            |       1         |   
|  2  | ['DDD','AAA']                      |       2         |   
|  3  | ['DDD','BBB', 'AAA', 'EEE', 'CCC'] |       5         |  
|  4  | ['EEE', 'AAA', 'EEE', 'CCC']       |       4         |
```

And the task consists of generating the following DataFrame:

```
|     |   Content       |   Unique    |  Started  |  Middleway  |  Finished  |
|  0  |     AAA         |     0       |     0     |      3      |      1     | 
|  1  |     BBB         |     0       |     1     |      1      |      0     |
|  2  |     CCC         |     1       |     0     |      0      |      3     |
|  3  |     DDD         |     0       |     2     |      0      |      0     |
|  4  |     EEE         |     0       |     1     |      2      |      0     |
```

where the columns contain the following:

- **Content**: the elements found in the **List**
- **Unique**: the number of times that the element appears alone in the list
- **Started**: the number of times that the element appears at the beginning
- **Finished**: the number of times that the element appears at the end
- **Middleway**: the number of times that the element appears between the beginning and the end.

I kind of got a solution for this task, but since I used a lot of loop functions, I can't apply the algorithm to a larger database because the time processing is too high. Could you help me by suggesting a code that solves this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution. First we apply enumerate on the List column, explode it and then sum() boolean columns:

```py
df = df.assign(List=df.List.apply(lambda x: [*enumerate(x, 1)])).explode("List")
df[["tmp", "Content"]] = df["List"].apply(pd.Series)

df["Unique"] = df.tmp.eq(1).eq(df.Path_length)
df["Started"] = df.tmp.eq(1) & ~df.Unique
df["Middleway"] = df.tmp.ne(1) & df.tmp.ne(df.Path_length)
df["Finished"] = df.tmp.eq(df.Path_length) & ~df.Unique

print(df.groupby("Content").sum().iloc[:, 2:].reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
  Content  Unique  Started  Middleway  Finished
0     AAA       0        0          3         1
1     BBB       0        1          1         0
2     CCC       1        0          0         3
3     DDD       0        2          0         0
4     EEE       0        1          2         0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach:

You can `mask` the paths where the length is 1 (replace values where the condition is True to an empty string `""` so that you can `explode` the lists to count the values in them).

Then for those rows, count the "Started", "Middleway" and "Finished" values using `value_counts`.

Then, for the rows where the length is 1, count the "Unique" values.

Finally, drop the dummy `""` index, `sort` and rearrange the columns to get the desired outcome:

```
masked_df = df['List'].mask(df['Path_length']==1, '')
out = masked_df.explode().value_counts().to_frame().rename(columns={'List': 'Finished'}).rename_axis(index=['Content'])
out['Started'] = masked_df.str[0].value_counts()
out['Middleway'] = masked_df.str[1:-1].explode().value_counts()
out['Finished'] -= out[['Started','Middleway']].sum(axis=1)
out['Unique'] = df['List'].where(df['Path_length']==1, '').explode().value_counts()
out = out.drop(index='').fillna(0).astype(int).sort_index().reset_index()[['Content','Unique','Started','Middleway','Finished']]
```

Output:

```
  Content  Unique  Started  Middleway  Finished
0     AAA       0        0          3         1
1     BBB       0        1          1         0
2     CCC       1        0          0         3
3     DDD       0        2          0         0
4     EEE       0        1          2         0
```